# Проблема с открытие exe файла после создание через pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Сформировал exe файл на pyinstaller, но при его открытии вылетает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\90C5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI111882\\distributed\\distributed.yaml'
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Scheduler.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import *
import os
import re
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
os.chdir(desktop)
if not os.path.isdir("Графикователь"):
     os.mkdir("Графикователь")
os.chdir(desktop + "\\Графикователь")

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [400,200]
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=15)
plt.rc('font', size=70)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

#Auxiliary data
#Dictionary
dictionaryRM = {'TD_11_1Suprarex SXE-P3 4500_1.1':[0.5, 2, 2, 12, 0, 0.75, 1]}

#List of RM in queue
listQueueRM = ['TD_11_1Suprarex SXE-P3 4500_1.1']


class Ui_Scheduler(object):
    def setupUi(self, Scheduler):
        Scheduler.setObjectName("Scheduler")
        Scheduler.resize(1109, 645)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Scheduler)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 380, 241, 101))
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))
        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.OLaunch = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Scheduler)
        self.OLaunch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 50, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.OLaunch.setFont(font)
        self.OLaunch.setObjectName("OLaunch")
        self.TLaunch = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Scheduler)
        self.TLaunch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 90, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.TLaunch.setFont(font)
        self.TLaunch.setObjectName("TLaunch")
        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(Scheduler)
        self.calendar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 40, 421, 231))
        self.calendar.setObjectName("calendar")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Scheduler)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 500, 241, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Scheduler)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 151, 31))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Scheduler)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 240, 151, 31))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.Start = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Scheduler)
        self.Start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 280, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Start.setFont(font)
        self.Start.setObjectName("Start")
        self.Finish = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Scheduler)
        self.Finish.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 280, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Finish.setFont(font)
        self.Finish.setObjectName("Finish")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(26, 53, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 170, 401, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 200, 401, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.PlanExcel = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Scheduler)
        self.PlanExcel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 380, 261, 31))
        self.PlanExcel.setObjectName("PlanExcel")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 380, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.LaborExcel = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Scheduler)
        self.LaborExcel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 430, 261, 31))
        self.LaborExcel.setObjectName("LaborExcel")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 430, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 480, 441, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.NameFile = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Scheduler)
        self.NameFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 480, 261, 31))
        self.NameFile.setObjectName("NameFile")
        self.DatePZ = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Scheduler)
        self.DatePZ.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 530, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.DatePZ.setFont(font)
        self.DatePZ.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.DatePZ.setObjectName("DatePZ")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 621, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 560, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(6)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Scheduler)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 600, 1071, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Verdana")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
 
        self.step = 0

        self.retranslateUi(Scheduler)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Scheduler)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.TotalFunction)
        self.OLaunch.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.TLaunch.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.Start.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.Finish.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.DatePZ.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())

    def retranslateUi(self, Scheduler):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Scheduler.setWindowTitle(_translate("Scheduler", "Графикователь"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Запустить расчет"))
        self.textEdit_4.setHtml(_translate("Scheduler", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">Начало периода</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_5.setHtml(_translate("Scheduler", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">Окончание периода</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Укажите дату запуска изделий ОКШ и ДШ"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Укажите дату запуска изделий ТШС и ПШС"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Укажите временные границы отгрузки"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "запланированных изделий"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Введите название файла excel - План"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Введите название файла excel - Трудоемкость"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Введите название файла для сохранения графика"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Scheduler", "Введите дату ----> Сформируется файл с указанием РЦ и количеством по ПЗ"))



    def TotalFunction(self):
        """
        This function combines all functions
        """
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)

        
        df = pd.read_excel(self.PlanExcel.text())

        # Получение дополнительных параметров, необходимых для расчета

        def BuildGantGraph(ds):
            """
            Gant graph is built of the function.
            """

            ds["Quantity"] = ds["Quantity"].astype(int)
        
            l_drop_col = []
            for i in ds.columns[29:]:
                if i not in dataBase['Наименование РЦ'].tolist():
                    l_drop_col.append(i)
        
            ds.drop(l_drop_col, axis=1, inplace=True)
           

            colors = []
            for i in range(4):
                for y in mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.values():
                    colors.append(y)
            random.shuffle(colors)

            fig, gnt = plt.subplots()

            # Setting Y-axis limits
            gnt.set_ylim(0, len(dataBase) * 10)

            # Setting X-axis limits
            if launchOK > launchTS:
                gnt.set_xlim(launchTS, launchTS + relativedelta(months=2))
            else:
                gnt.set_xlim(launchOK, launchOK + relativedelta(months=2))
        
           # Setting labels for x-axis and y-axis
            gnt.set_xlabel('Timeline')
            gnt.set_ylabel('Operations')

            # Setting ticks on y-axis
            gnt.set_yticks([i for i in range(5, (len(dataBase) * 10)+5, 10)])
            # Labelling tickes of y-axis
            gnt.set_yticklabels(list(dataBase['Наименование РЦ']))

            # Setting graph attribute
            gnt.grid(False)

            # Create dictionaries to calculte certain kind of products
            dictionaryOfWorkCenter = dict()
            dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter = dict()
            dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC = dict()
            for i in dataBase.index:
                dictionaryOfWorkCenter.setdefault(dataBase['Наименование РЦ'][i], 0)
                dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter.setdefault(dataBase['Наименование РЦ'][i], datetime(2022, 12, 1, 8, 0, 0))
                dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC.setdefault(dataBase['Наименование РЦ'][i], 0)

            # List of variables
            launch = launchTS
            deltaTime = timedelta(hours = 0)
            timeOfMachine = 0
            c = 0
            # Algorithm for draw

            for i in ds.index:  # Loop on PZ

                if ds['Вид изделия'][i] == 'ОКШ' or ds['Вид изделия'][i] == 'ДШ' or ds['Вид изделия'][i] == 'Муфта' \
                    or ds['Вид изделия'][i] == 'Прочая продукция':
                    continue
    
                deltaTime += timedelta(hours=dictionaryOfWorkCenter['TD_11_1Suprarex SXE-P3 4500_1.2'])
                start = launch + deltaTime

                c += 1

                for k, v in zip(ds.columns[29:], dataBase.index):  # Loop on work center

                    # Check the execution of operations on the work center
                    if ds[k][i] == 0:
                        continue

                    # Correct start
                    if start < dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k]:
                        start = dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k]

                    # Check the enough time of work center
                    if dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC[k] >= dataBase['availableTime'][v]:

                        # Temporary variable to change start if time of machine are reached
                        delta = (timedelta(hours=24) - timedelta(hours=dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC[k]))

                        if delta > timedelta(hours=0):
                            start += delta
                        else:
                            start += timedelta(hours=0)

                        dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC[k] = 0
                        dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k] = start

                    # Update variables
                    timeOfTask = 0
                    counter = 0

                    for j in (range(ds['Quantity'][i])):  # Loop on quantity of PZ

                        timeOfMachine += ds[k][i] / dataBase['Кол-во единиц оборудования, шт'][v]
                        timeOfTask += ds[k][i] / dataBase['Кол-во единиц оборудования, шт'][v]
                        counter += 1

                    gnt.broken_barh([((start, timedelta(hours=np.float64(timeOfTask))))], (v * 10, 5), \
                                    facecolors = mcolors.to_rgba(colors[c], 0.5))
                    if dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k] >= startDatePZ and dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k] <= finishDatePZ:
                        dataOpPZ.setdefault(k, {}).setdefault(ds["Номер ПЗ"][i], 0)
                        dataOpPZ[k][ds["Номер ПЗ"][i]] += counter

                    start += timedelta(hours=np.float64(timeOfTask))

                    #plt.text(start, v * 10, f'{counter} - {ds["Номер ПЗ"][i]}')

                    # Add timeOfTask into dict to each work center
                    dictionaryOfWorkCenter[k] = timeOfTask
                    dictionaryEndOfWorkCenter[k] = start
                    dictionaryTimeMachineOfWC[k] += timeOfMachine
                    timeOfMachine = 0

            fileName = f'Данные по количеству в ПЗ на рабочих центрах на {datePZ}.xlsx'
            pd.DataFrame(dataOpPZ).to_excel(fileName)
            self.label_9.setText(f"Файл сохранен")
            self.label_10.setText(f"Все файлы расположены в директории {os.getcwd()}")
            self.step += 12
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)
            gnt.axvspan(startPlan, finishPlan, color="blue", alpha=0.05)
            plt.savefig(self.NameFile.text())
            plt.show()        
                
        BuildGantGraph(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("project_plan_22131.png"))
    Scheduler = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Scheduler()
    ui.setupUi(Scheduler)
    Scheduler.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: исходники покажете ?

Comment: Конечно, сейчас отредактирую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом, при формировании добавил еще один флаг:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/distributed/distributed.yaml;./distributed" script.py
```